# Java EE NullPointerException with CDI and web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, cdi

I am trying to implement a demo web service but I struggle with CDI. I want to inject `FooFinder` into `FooBooker` but I am getting `null` instead (there is a NullPointerException during the call of FooResponse as fooFinder is null).

I have an interface

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public interface FooFinder {

    FooResponse getReply(String origin, String destination);
}
```

implemented like

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class MockedFoo implements FooFinder {

    @Override
    public FooResponse getReply(String origin, String destination) {
        String s = "SuperFoo";
        Double d = 123.45;
    return new FooResponse(origin, destination, s, d);
    }
}
```

within a web service

```
@WebService
public class FooBooker {
    @Inject
    FooFinder fooFinder;

    @WebMethod
    public FooResponse getReply(String origin, String destination) {
        return fooFinder.getReply(origin, destination);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Object implementor = new FooBooker();
        String address = "http://localhost:9000/FooBooker";
        Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Annotate the webservice as ```@Stateless``` to make it an EJB bean, so that it can be registered with CDI as an EJB bean. additionally, you are calling main, from the webservice. Thats not how webservices are designed to operate. This is supposed to be managed by an application server with EJB and CDI containers

Comment: @maress adding `@Stateless` results in _Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type FooFinder with qualifiers @Default_
The `main()` part comes from Idea WebServices sample code.

Comment: Be sure that the ```@RequestScoped``` annotation is a ```javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped``` not a ```javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a problem with CDI libraries setup. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I have enabled CDI support in GlassFish configuration dialogue.

[image: GlassFish configuration]

Injection however didn’t work until I added CDI support in Modules configuration.

[image: Modules configuration]